# In ConTeXt, why are my float elements 'overlapping' between columns?

Tags: floats, context, two-column

Here is an extract of a document I produced. On the right column, the red background stops for the height the left column table, even though it should not.

[image: Page with the wrong display]

If I remove the table on the left, then the block on the right is correctly drawn (red background and dark red border around all text).

Here is a minimal working example that lead to the issue:

```
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document main configuration
\setupcolumns[n=2,balance=no]                   % document columns nb, fill 1st col first

% Exemples float
\definetextbackground[examplebg][%
    location=paragraph,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=red,
]
\define[2]\atdmexample{%                        % define a macro for using examples background
    \startexamplebg
        {\tfa\em #1}                            % example title as it appears inside the ex frame
        \blank[big]

        #2%                                     % - exemple content
    \stopexamplebg
}

\starttext


    %---------------------------------------------------------------------
    \startcolumns

    \dorecurse{16}{This is a dummy text in order to occupy some space. }

    \placetable[here][table:my_table]{My Table}
    {\bTABLE
     \bTR \bTD XXXXXX \eTD \bTD  YYYYYY \eTD \eTR
    \eTABLE}

    \dorecurse{11}{This is a dummy text in order to occupy some space. }

    \atdmexample{My Example}{%
    \dorecurse{31}{This is a dummy text in order to occupy some space. }

    }

    \stopcolumns



\stoptext
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: It would be great, if you could make your example compilable (one code snippet we can copy and paste to see the issue, which does compile, i.e. has no undefined colors etc.)

Comment: Just edited the question with a mwe.

Comment: @Silverspur You can use `\dorecurse{10}{...}` to create multiple lines of the same text because your example doesn't show the problem mentioned above. To fill the gap in the background add `\setupfloat[freeregion=no]` to your document.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster That's interesting. What exactly does `freeregion` do?

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster I've updated my question with `\dorecurse`. I have not yet been able to test `freeregion`, but I'm also interested in what this does!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ConTeXt doesn't place text backgrounds behind floats in the standard setting. The calculation for the needed space takes on the vertical position and margin settings )or for side floats the width of the float content) into account but not multiple columns as in your case.

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]

\definetextbackground
  [example]
  [location=paragraph,
   background=color,
   backgroundcolor=red]

\setuppapersize[A5]

%\setupfloats[freeregion=no]

\starttext

\starttextbackground[example]

\input linden

\placefigure
  {Dummy figure}
  {\externalfigure[dummy]}

\input weisman

\stoptextbackground

\stoptext
```

[image]

You can disable this feature with the `freeregion=no` seeting for `\setupfloat` which places text background behind floats. As a result of this the gap in the background in your example disappears.

[image]